# Richtextbox (RTE) link.aspx custom links are not clickable

Tags: sitecore-commerce

Apologies for any wrong terminology used in here.

We're generating the links from Sitecore using `<a href="~/link.aspx?_id=B455DD7B519040C3A694155227E08A85&amp;_z=z">` and they're rendering on the page with
`<a href="https://prodcommercecm.domain.com:443/path/page" class="link link-arrow">Link</a>`. Generated link in the above anchor tag is correct and if I copy the link and open in a new page it is loading the page, but if I click on the link on the page it's not redirecting to the page and not doing anything.
If I replace the URL to relative path in the DOM like `<a href="/path/page" class="link link-arrow">Link</a>` It's redirecting the page. I need help in understanding why the absolute URL click doesn't work and a solution to this, if there is any.

Comment: Try removing the domain name and port from href

Comment: Link can NOT be unclickable. Looks like CSS/JS blocking. Try to remove class value to check.

Answer (score 1):

You can control the way how Sitecore should build the URLs using some properties of the Link Builder.

One such property is **AlwaysIncludeServerUrl** which is of boolean type.
It Specifies whether the server URL is always included while generating the URL.
You can check the value set for the property in the Sitecore.config file or any other patch file that modifies the link manager properties. If you are generating the link programatically, you can use the *UrlBuilderOptions* class with the property *AlwaysIncludeServerUrl*.